# For Next Loop - Increase Variable

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I have a basic for next loop.

```
For x = 1 to 100
    test = Test +110
    if test > 500
        counter = Counter +1
    end if

    MsgBox (thisisatest)
Next
```

What i'd like to do, increase thisisatest by 1 each time the counter increases.  For example.

```
If counter = '1' it should be 'thisisatest1'
If Counter = '2' it should be 'thisisatest2'
If counter = '3' it should be 'thisisatest3'
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Are you asking for an array or for string concatenation?

Comment: I'm open to whatever works.  Would an array work?

Comment: It depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Is `thisisatest` of type `Integer` or `String`?

Comment: 'thisisatest' is string

Comment: `MsgBox("thisisatest" & counter.ToString())` Note that you have to convert the number `counter` to a string to be able to combine it with a string.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think that even with `Option Strict On`, `MsgBox("thisisatest" & counter)` works, I suppose because `Integer` can be widened to a `String`, which is what the [& operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk.aspx) requires (although I can't find any docs that there is a widening operator from `Integer` to `String`).

Comment: @Mark Good point, but shhh! please :) It makes it completely obvious what is intended if `.ToString()` is used.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Clear, obvious code - where is the job security in that?  Agree 100% - I should have disengaged pedant mode!

Answer (score 1):

```
For x = 1 to 100
    test = Test +110
    if test > 500
        counter = Counter +1
    end if

    MsgBox (thisisatest+counter)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

you can increase your variable thisisatest by 1 each time the counter increases as below:

```
For x = 1 to 100
    test = Test +110
    if test > 500
        counter = Counter +1
        thisisatest &= x
    end if

    MsgBox (thisisatest)
Next
```

Comment: Hint: try that with [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx). You should always use that Option, and you'll know the exceptions to that if you ever come across them.

Comment: i concat the thisisatest with the value of Counter (x) so the result will be as the asker wants.

Comment: @Dotnetter The `thisisatest` variable is not initialized within the loop, so the concatenations will accumulate.  Also, `counter` and `x` do not have the same values.  How they are initialized is a bit of a mystery, though! :-)

Comment: @Dotnetter We can tell you didn't test that code because it's missing the "Then". And if you'd copy-and-pasted it from working code it would have the keywords capitalized. It's a good idea to test code which you propose as an answer.

Comment: i don't have visual studio in my current computer, so i wrote it handly.